# Why does the hard-coded url work but not the name-spaced url in Django?

Tags: python, django

I need someone that really knows their Django. So I can always give more detail if it's necessary but long story short, I'm trying to link to urls using django's url tag and I get a NoReverseMatch exception everytime.

```
<ul>
    {% for item in results %} 
         <li><a href="{% url 'cards:stats' item.title %}">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

BUT, when I use the hardcoded url, this works perfectly fine:

```
<ul>
    {% for item in results %} 
         <li><a href="/cards/stats/{{ item.title }}">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This is what the url.py module looks like:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'cards'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('search/', views.search, name='search'),
    path('search-results/<keywords>/', views.search_results, name='search-results'),
    path('stats/<item_title>/', views.stats, name='stats')
]
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? Let me know if you need more details. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you plz share your urls.py

Comment: Ok just added the url.py module code.

Comment: OK,  there is no pb with you urls.py, try this =>  href="{% url 'stats' item_title=item.title %}"

Comment: I tried it. It didn't work :( I still get a NoReverseMatch exception. It says that "Reverse for 'stats' not found. 'stats' is not a valid view function or pattern name."

Comment: Please share your project urls.py file

Comment: what is the error message with href="{% url 'cards:stats' item_title=item.title %}"